# How to draw a vertical line from the intersection of two curves in a graph, when manipulate is used

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I have a manipulate function that creates two lines in a x-y coordinates system, what I want know is a vertical line pointing to the x-axis-intercept, where those two lines intercept

Comment: I'm sure you can get quite far searching around for "lines intersection" and "vertical line". Have you tried anything? Additionally, how do you expect to get help if we don't know how your lines are represented? Please do the searching and let us know where exactly are you stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = Sin;
g = Cos;
Manipulate[Normal[Plot[{a f[x],b g[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {a f[#] -b g[#] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]] /. Point[x_] :> 
    {Thickness[.01], Red, CapForm["Round"], Line[{{x[[1]], 0}, x}], Black, Point[x]},
 {{a, 1}, -2, 2}, {{b, 1}, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Variation on @kglr's approach (somewhat simpler, but you also get additional boundary edges):

```
f = Sin;
g = Cos;
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{x, a f[x] t}, {x, b g[x] t}},
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1},
  MeshFunctions -> {a f[#] - b g[#] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> {None, None}],
 {{a, 1}, -2, 2}, {{b, 1}, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]